# C - Running an executable and waiting until it's finished

Tags: c, file-io, exe

I'm writing a test program that needs to call 2 separate exe files, wait for them to finish and output their csv files, then read in those resultant files.

I'm currently using `_popen` to create a pipe and show me the output, but I don't really need any of that and looping until `feof` seems pointless.

What I'd like to have is this:

- I launch my application which pops up in it's own cmd window.
- It calls exe1 which does everything in it's own window.
- It calls exe2 which does everything in it's own window.
- When both have exited it continues.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

EDIT: Playing around I've found that using `System("exe1");` does essentially what I'm doing now, but in one line. Or am I missing something here?

```
int runTest(char* testName)
{
    char psBuffer[128];
    FILE *pPipe;

    if ((pPipe = _popen(testName, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s", testName);
        return 0;
    }

    while (fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe))
    {
        printf(psBuffer);
    }

    if (feof(pPipe))
    {
        printf("%s returned %d\n", testName, _pclose(pPipe));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using windows? For unix you can do a [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) and then exec from the child and wait in the parent for the appropriate PID (redirecting the stdin/stdout of the child if necessary). Maybe for windows similar solution will also work, but I cannot give you any details...

Comment: `system( "path\\to\\your.exe" );` does what you want. If you need the exit value that the executable exits with, just check the return value from the `system` call. This is trie for Windows at least...

Answer (score 0):

You can thread them like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void*           thread_2(void *arg)
{
  system("./exec2");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void*           thread_1(void *arg)
{
  system("./exec1");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* (*func_ptr[2])(void*) = { thread_1, thread_2 };

void            main()
{
  pthread_t     thread_pool[2];

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_create(&thread_pool[i], NULL, func_ptr[i], NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_join(thread_pool[i], NULL);
}
```

Hope this will help you.